# Configurable Swatches Playing Up

Tags: swatches

On this item: 
https://sssextreme.com/westbeach-twist-ski-snowboard-ladies-jacket-rasberry-sinatra-blue.html
It works fine 100%

But some items like this one below
https://sssextreme.com/twf-adults-xt3-full-wetsuits.html
It does not swatch, but it does on the category pages like below
https://sssextreme.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=TWF+ADULTS+XT3+FULL+WETSUITS[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rename this `XXL - 47- 50"` because in 1.9.1 configurable swatch images do not swap correctly if attribute label contains ' " ' (quotes)

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/559

or

Copy app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/media/js.phtml to your local theme

Then change Line # 35

From

```
ConfigurableMediaImages.setImageFallback(<?php echo $imageFallback['product']->getId(); ?>, $j.parseJSON('<?php echo $imageFallback['image_fallback']; ?>'));
```

To

```
ConfigurableMediaImages.setImageFallback(<?php echo $imageFallback['product']->getId(); ?>, $j.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($imageFallback['image_fallback']); ?>));
```

Comment: Changing the code worked like a charm, thanks so much for your time.